Compiling for an earlier version of JRE using language constructs from later JDK versions
I have a question about compiling a programme for an earlier version of JRE. I have JDK 21 installed on my work computer (and it is also connected in Eclipse).
Case 1. There is a common Eclipse project with the following setting: Compiler compliance level -> 1.8
And the programme code
public class Test21Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> fixedSizeList = Arrays.asList(‘Male’, ‘Female’);
        String last = fixedSizeList.getLast();
        System.out.println(last);
    }
}

The IDE shows an error in the editor on the method getLast(); - The method getLast() is undefined for the type List<String> (because this method appeared only in JDK21). Accordingly, this project cannot be compiled because there is a Unresolved compilation problem: The method getLast() is undefined for the type List<String>
Case 2. There is a Maven project, in which in pom.xml is specified
<properties>
<project.java.version>1.8</project.java.version>
</properties>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${project.java.version}</source>
        <target>${project.java.version}</target>                
    </configuration>
</plugin>

I.e. this maven project will compile for jre 1.8 and moreover even the sources are specified as 1.8.
The getLast() method is also used in the code of this maven project, but it does not show any error in the IDE. This maven project compiles for jre 1.8, even though it uses the language construct for jdk 21.
So, it is not clear why the maven project does not show errors where the normal project in ide (Eclise) does? How the maven project compiles in an early version of jre (1.8), even though the source code uses a construct from jdk 21? I'm already repeating myself here, but only to describe the issues that cause misunderstandings.

I do not know Maven (not an expert) but it seems like it is still using the 21 library (which is usually not influenced by source/target arguments) -- you can create the same problem with Eclipse  by setting the JRE System Library in the Project Build Path to 21 (or newer) even if the compliance level is 1.8

see this question Specifying Java version in maven - differences between properties and compiler plugin

@user85421 realy, I removed from Project Build Path existing exucution environment and created a new one as JavaSE-1.8 (jdk-21) and now the ide shows error. Also there was wrong settings in pom project.java.version as it related to Spring boot accordint to the link you suggested.

Target means the bytecode can run on the target jre or later. source means the language only uses features that are supported. Eg. you cannot have a Record if you are using source level 8. getLast() is a method that satisfies both source and target requirements, but if you try to run it with JDK 8 then the method wont exist.

It sounds like Eclipse ecj is preventing you from shooting yourself in the foot by failing compilation if you use a method introduced in a newer Java version while targeting an older version.

@matt when you say features that are supported and getLast() is a method that satisfies both source and target requirements - is not the getLast() also a new feature of java 21 compared to 1.8? what's the difference? in fact I'm hardly familiar with java above 8...

Exactly the point. A language feature is something new to the language. Eg. var, record, pattern matching. They didn't didn't exist in java 8. getLast() is a new method. In a general sense it is a new feature, but it isn't a new feature of the language.  It's an addition to the library.

You can compile this, but it will not run under a JDK 8. For instance, it will fail with: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.List.getLast()Ljava/lang/Object;
To make sure that you compile something that will actually run under JDK 8, you need to set the property <maven.compiler.release> as well, or alternatively the <release> in the plugin configuration.
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.release>8</maven.compiler.release>
</properties>

If the code does not satisfy the parameter rule above, a compilation error will occur, e.g.
COMPILATION ERROR : cannot find symbol method getLast()
Setting the --release of the Java Compiler
